# Guid xml serialization & validation

Tags: xml, serialization, xsd, format, guid

Is it possible to specify how a Guid property should be formatted as a string when using XmlSerializer to serialize an object?

Pseudo code:

```
class MyObj {
    public Guid MyProp {get; set;}
}
```

the resulting XML after serialization looks like this, (the Guid is without braces { } )

```
<xml...>
  ..
  <MyProp>00000000-0000-0000-000000000000</MyProp>
  ..
</xml>
```

XSD for Guid as specified by Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/eventschema-guidtype-simpletype

Adding the Braces to the Guid requires calling `.ToString("B")`

Is there a way to tell the XmlSerializer how to format the Guid using a specific ToString format?

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work properly by doing this:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Guid MyProp { get; set; }

[XmlElement("MyProp")]
public string MyPropString
{
    get => MyProp.ToString("B");
    set => MyProp = Guid.Parse(value);
}
```